# How to use wxSpellCheckerDialog in Django?

Tags: python, django, wxpython

According to pyenchant [documentation](http://packages.python.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html) usage is follows,

```
>> import wx
>> from enchant.checker import SpellChecker
>> from enchant.checker.wxSpellCheckerDialog import wxSpellCheckerDialog
>>
>> app = wx.PySimpleApp()
>> text = "This is sme text with a fw speling errors in it. Here are a fw more to tst it ut."
>> dlg = wxSpellCheckerDialog(None,-1,"")
>> chkr = SpellChecker("en_US",text)
>> dlg.SetSpellChecker(chkr)
>> dlg.Show()
>> app.MainLoop()
```

This opens spell correction dialogbox.

So how can i get modified text back ?

**EDIT 1 :**

text = chkr.get_text() returns corrected text. But I'm getting following error.

PyAssertionError at /quiz/submit/
C++ assertion "wxThread::IsMain()" failed at ....\src\msw\evtloop.cpp(244) in wxEventLoop::Dispatch(): only the main thread can process Windows messages

This is the code i implemented

```
app = wx.PySimpleApp()
text = "This is sme text with a fw speling errors in it. Here are a fw more to tst it ut."
dlg = wxSpellCheckerDialog(None,-1,"")
chkr = SpellChecker("en_US",text)
dlg.SetSpellChecker(chkr)
dlg.ShowModal()
text = chkr.get_text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you call `chkr.getText()` which returns the corrected text.

Comment: Thanks :) It worked at first correction. Running it again by refreshing page giving follwing error. PyAssertionError at /quiz/submit/
C++ assertion "wxThread::IsMain()" failed at ..\..\src\msw\evtloop.cpp(244) in wxEventLoop::Dispatch(): only the main thread can process Windows messages

Comment: You're running the GUI spell-checker from what I can see in a Django app (didn't see that tag when I first posted)? This will be your problem.

Comment: At a guess, whatever webserver is serving Django is creating a thread for the first visit, which creates a WX thread for your spell checker. The first Django thread is then discarded. The second visit starts a second Django thread and tries to create a second WX thread which complains because it's not the main WX thread.