# Using wxSpellCheckerDialog in Django is causing a C++ "wxThread::IsMain()" assertion failure

Tags: python, django, wxpython

Continued from [How to use wxSpellCheckerDialog in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474971/how-to-use-wxspellcheckerdialog-python-django/10476811#comment13562681_10476811)

I have added spell checking to Django application using pyenchant.

It works correctly when first run. But when I call it again (or after several runs) it gives following error.

[image]

> PyAssertionError at /quiz/submit/
>
> C++ assertion "wxThread::IsMain()"
> failed at ....\src\msw\evtloop.cpp(244) in wxEventLoop::Dispatch():
> only the main thread can process Windows messages

How to fix this?

Comment: Just a note: you are fully aware that actually you're executing some wxPython code server-side? So your window is created/shown on the server when django processes an http request?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need wxPython to use pyEnchant. And you certainly shouldn't be using wx stuff with django. wxPython is for desktop GUIs, while django is a web app framework. As "uhz" pointed out, you can't call wxPython methods outside the main thread that wxPython runs in unless you use its threadsafe methods, such as wx.CallAfter. I don't know why you'd call wxPython from Django though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use wx controls from inside Django code, is that correct? If so you are doing a very weird thing :)

When you write a GUI application with wxPython there is one main thread which can process Window messages - the main thread is defined as the one where wx.App was created. You are trying to do a UI thing from a non-UI thread. So probably at first run everything works (everything is performed in the GUI thread) but on second attempt a different python thread (spawned by django?) is performing some illegal GUI actions. You could try using wx.CallAfter which would execute a function from the argument in GUI thread but this is non-blocking. Also I've found something you might consider: wxAnyThread [wxAnyThread](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wxAnyThread). But I didn't use it and I don't know if it applies in your case.